# How to use unordered_set with compare function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unordered-set

I wrote my own compare function for the third template parameter of std::unorderd_set.
My function is

```
static bool HasSamePosition(const Node& a, const Node& b);
```

in the class Node. Now I'm trying to use this function in my unordered set,

```
std::unordered_set<Node, std::hash<Node>, bool(*)(const Node& a, const Node& b)> closedlist(&Node::HasSamePosition);
```

but it doesn't work. The error ist, that no instance of the constructor is matching the argumentlist. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to fill in the default arguments for the constructor. Or, even better, wrap the function call in a default constructible function object and pass the type of that as a template parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the compiler is right. There is no constructor that allows you to only pass `KeyEqual` as parameter. You need to use another constructor (see [here](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set)) or change the type of your function.

E.g. You could use a helper struct that wraps around your HasSamePosition call and override `operator()(const Node& a, const Node& b)`

```
struct Node{
    static bool HasSamePosition(const Node& a, const Node& b);
};

struct NodeEqual
{
    bool operator()(const Node& a, const Node& b) { return Node::HasSamePosition(a, b); }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<Node, std::hash<Node>, NodeEqual> closedlist();
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment on the other answer.

Comment: @Simon Kraemer how do you suggest to choose the bucket_count constructor parameter, e.g. if I have a maximum of ~400 elements in my unordered_set?

Comment: @user3561614 I can't decide this w/o having any more information. But since you don't need to pass anything but your `KeyEqual` type/instance: I would recommend to use the `operator()()` method by declaring an extra struct. Either inside your class as in Garf365s answer or as an extra struct as in mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use a class:

```
class Node
{ 
    public:
        class HasSamePosition
        {
            bool operator()(const Node& a, const Node& b)
            { 
                // Put here content of your HasSamePosition function
            }
        };
    ....
};

std::unordered_set<Node, std::hash<Node>, Node::HasSamePosition> closedlist;
```

Comment: Remove the parens, it's the function declaration.

Comment: @milleniumbug I don't understand your comment, can you explain ?

Comment: `A b();` is the function declaration due to how C++ parses it. In order to declare a variable you need `A b;` (compare `int main();` to `int var;`)